# Can't display target array within object using *ngFor

Tags: angular

I have an angular app where for one view I'm displaying a list of contact phone numbers.

Example of my object:

contact: {
    name:'sam smith',
    phones:[
        {phone_type:'home', phone_number:'222-222-2222'},
        {phone_type:'mobile', phone_number:'333-333-3333'}
    ]
}

In my html I can access the contact name with {{contact.name}}

But if I try to loop the phones array with *ngFor like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let phone of contact.phones">{{phone.phone_number}}</div>
```

I get:

"ContactEditPage.html:61 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'phones' of undefined".

So I know the object is being returned, but why can't I look through the phones array?

Comment: It's most likely because you're loading the data asynchronously and you should initialize contact as an object ```{}```

Answer (score 2):

You should use safe navigation operator to check if the values are there because your api call return the data asynchronously

```
<div *ngFor="let phone of contact?.phones">{{phone?.phone_number}}</div>
```

Comment: Does '?' make the call asynchronous?

Comment: no it wont throw undefined error until you get the data from the api

Comment: That did it. Thanks!!